# What places a question on the Questions:Faq subpage?

Tags: support

There are several questions which have high views and high votes on the page which makes a good bit of sense. But there are also some weak questions, unvoted/unanswered questions, and one that's actually been closed.

What qualifications/mechanisms puts a question over there? Could this be not working correctly?

Comment: I'll ping some people that know more about this than me.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112263/how-are-the-faq-questions-chosen

Answer (score 1):

Judging from my [link in the comments and here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112263/how-are-the-faq-questions-chosen) to M.SO, it appears that questions that have the most internal links (e.g., I referenced question X while answering/commenting question Y, so Question X's link score goes up) are placed upon the FAQ page.

Another piece of relevance : [LINK!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62210/how-are-the-tag-faq-selected)

Comment: This seems to need some form of override. As it seems it would be easy to stuff a post with links and not be useful at all.

Comment: @AndreiFreeman I would tend to agree with you there.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The ideal of the page is that questions that are referenced often are those that are, well, frequently asked (duplicates), or whose answers are component to a number of questions asked on the site (hence the linkage). As for stuffing posts with links, if it's not helpful, then you can always motion for that stuff to be edited out or deleted.

Comment: @GraceNote Thanks for the added info.